# Logistic Regression glm() in R not recognizing numerical values

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I'm fairly new to R and machine learning and I'm trying to build a logistic regression model that can predict which of the clinical variables can better predict the outcome of death (0 being death and 1 is living in the dataset below).

Here is the dput of the data

```
structure(list(ID = c(13154920, 13201107, 13207948, 13234892, 
13082943, 13193903, 13283776, 13154288, 13269178, 13055690, 13207670, 
13220627, 13055009, 13044947, 13060589, 13201616, 13054278, 13160156, 
13160971, 13239318, 13321288, 13154966, 13165362, 12999835, 13223721, 
13064865, 13104602, 13036280, 13040507, 12964437, 13029805, 13029001, 
12993036, 13072516, 13060586, 13119819, 13040632, 13055908, 13059026, 
13207119, 13261022, 13259391, 13262499, 13207315, 13135316, 13233898, 
13181075, 13261607, 13186960, 13240091, 13260671, 13302375, 13021555, 
13062360, 13035346, 13077712, 13128769, 13267480, 13040172, 12977871, 
13090190, 13040530, 13100979, 13192142, 13289317, 13315577, 13044653, 
13079694, 13128639, 13207352, 13049409, 13210994, 13283675), 
    outcome = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1), day = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), pa02 = c("121", "NA", "78.7", "69.099999999999994", "131", 
    "26.3", "68.900000000000006", "74.099999999999994", "118", 
    "404", "399", "NA", "NA", "73.7", "265", "75", "222", "112", 
    "133", "77.900000000000006", "64.7", "84", "92.2", "107", 
    "64.599999999999994", "56.6", "69.900000000000006", "130", 
    "91.4", "NA", "111", "79.2", "86.9", "65.7", "94.5", "129", 
    "NA", "157,0", "32,8", "160,0", "38,1", "61,7", "NA", "86,8", 
    "86,5", "87,4", "143,0", "57,8", "NA", "88,6", "94,3", "NA", 
    "70,0", "107,0", "57,2", "75,9", "148,0", "NA", "60,4", "NA", 
    "NA", "148,0", "75,3", "75,4", "58", "46,4", "82,3", "189,0", 
    "132,0", "96,5", "112,0", "67,0", "65"), iot = c("0", "1", 
    "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", 
    "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0"), fio2 = c("0.23", 
    "1", "0.6", "0.23", "1", "0.23", "0.23", "0.23", "0.4", "1", 
    "0.23", "0.23", "0.23", "1", "0.23", "0.23", "0.23", "0.23", 
    "0.5", "0.5", "0.23", "0.23", "0.23", "0.23", "0.75", "NA", 
    "NA", "0.23", "0.1", "0.23", "NA", "0.23", "NA", "0.23", 
    "1", "0.5", "0.4", "0.45", "0.23", "0.23", "0.7", "0.23", 
    "0.23", "0.23", "0.23", "0.23", "1", "0.23", "0.23", "0.23", 
    "0.23", "0.23", "0.23", "1", "0.23", "1", "0.23", "0.8", 
    "0.23", "0.4", "0.23", "0.4", "0.23", "0.23", "0.23", "0.23", 
    "0.3", "0.23", "0.8", "0.23", "0.3", "0.23", "0.23"), resp_syst = c("526.08695652173913", 
    "NA", "131.16666666666669", "300.43478260869563", "131", 
    "114.34782608695652", "299.56521739130437", "322.17391304347819", 
    "295", "404", "1734.782608695652", "NA", "NA", "73.7", "1152.1739130434783", 
    "326.08695652173913", "965.21739130434776", "486.95652173913044", 
    "266", "155.80000000000001", "281.30434782608694", "365.21739130434781", 
    "400.86956521739131", "465.21739130434781", "86.133333333333326", 
    "NA", "NA", "565.21739130434776", "914", "NA", "NA", "344.3478260869565", 
    "NA", "285.6521739130435", "94.5", "258", "NA", "348.88888888888886", 
    "142.60869565217391", "695.6521739130435", "54.428571428571431", 
    "268.26086956521738", "NA", "377.39130434782606", "376.08695652173913", 
    "380", "143", "251.30434782608694", "NA", "385.21739130434776", 
    "409.99999999999994", "NA", "304.3478260869565", "107", "248.69565217391303", 
    "75.900000000000006", "643.47826086956513", "NA", "262.60869565217388", 
    "NA", "NA", "370", "327.39130434782606", "327.82608695652175", 
    "252.17391304347825", "201.7391304347826", "274.33333333333331", 
    "821.73913043478262", "165", "419.56521739130432", "373.33333333333337", 
    "291.30434782608694", "282.60869565217388"), resp_score = c(0, 
    NA, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, NA, NA, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 
    3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 4, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 1, NA, 2, 4, 2, NA, 
    1, 2, 0, 4, 2, NA, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, NA, 1, 0, NA, 1, 3, 2, 
    4, 0, NA, 2, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2), 
    platelets = c("NA", "363000", "NA", "NA", "620000", "NA", 
    "419000", "277000", "NA", "NA", "277000", "255000", "NA", 
    "185000", "318000", "296000", "182000", "48000", "129000", 
    "260000", "254000", "213000", "132000", "293000", "NA", "99000", 
    "297000", "227000", "174000", "172000", "76000", "NA", "242000", 
    "181000", "90000", "NA", "NA", "264000", "331000", "237000", 
    "279000", "NA", "214000", "NA", "NA", "283000", "416000", 
    "349000", "NA", "243000", "635000", "100000", "165000", "343000", 
    "NA", "423000", "206000", "NA", "439000", "NA", "358000", 
    "253000", "130000", "NA", "498000", "415000", "236000", "440000", 
    "218000", "300000", "190000", "244000", "275000"), coag_score = c(NA, 
    0, NA, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, NA, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, NA, 0, 0, 2, NA, 
    NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 
    NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 1, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), bilirrubin = c("NA", "0.4", "NA", "0.5", "0.3", "NA", 
    "0.9", "NA", "0.4", "NA", "0.5", "NA", "NA", "1.1000000000000001", 
    "NA", "0.3", "NA", "0.5", "NA", "0.3", "0.3", "NA", "NA", 
    "0.4", "NA", "0.5", "0.4", "0.4", "1", "0.5", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA", "0.3", "0.3", "1", "0.7", "0.3", "1.4", 
    "NA", "NA", "0.3", "0.3", "0.3", "0.7", "0.4", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA", "0.7", "0.6", "0.5", "NA", "NA", "0.3", "0.3", "NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "0.4", "0.3", "NA", "NA", "0.4", "1.1000000000000001", 
    "NA", "0.5", "1.4", "0.4", "0.6", "0.7"), liver_score = c(NA, 
    0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, 
    NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 
    0, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), pam = c("NA", "80.666666666666671", "73.333333333333329", 
    "83.333333333333329", "84.666666666666671", "100.6666666666667", 
    "101", "100", "95", "69.333333333333329", "93.666666666666671", 
    "70", "91.666666666666671", "70.666666666666671", "81.666666666666671", 
    "71.333333333333329", "95.333333333333329", "92", "77.666666666666671", 
    "84.333333333333329", "90", "80", "96.333333333333329", "93.333333333333329", 
    "69.333333333333329", "57.333333333333343", "80", "63", "81.666666666666671", 
    "80", "76.666666666666671", "90", "62.666666666666657", "89.333333333333329", 
    "87.333333333333329", "72.333333333333329", "93.333333333333329", 
    "87.666666666666671", "105.3333333333333", "107.6666666666667", 
    "69.333333333333329", "111.3333333333333", "75.666666666666671", 
    "103", "85.333333333333329", "86.666666666666671", "64.333333333333329", 
    "93.333333333333329", "87.333333333333329", "100", "106.6666666666667", 
    "96.666666666666671", "102", "98.666666666666671", "83.333333333333329", 
    "73.666666666666671", "95.333333333333329", "81", "93.333333333333329", 
    "62.666666666666657", "83.333333333333329", "93", "92.333333333333329", 
    "73.333333333333329", "87.333333333333329", "74.333333333333329", 
    "95.333333333333329", "80.333333333333329", "83.333333333333329", 
    "96.333333333333329", "97.666666666666671", "91.666666666666671", 
    "85.333333333333329"), catecolamine = c("10 ml/h", "0,1 mcg/kg/min", 
    "0", "0", "0,1mcg/kg/min", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0,8 mcg/kg/min", 
    "0,1 mcg/kg/min", "0", "0", "0,3mcg/kg/min", "0,15 mcg/kg/min", 
    "0,13mcg/kg/min", "6ml/h", "0", "0", "0,03mcg/kg/min", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "9mL/h", "0", "0", "0.45", "5.5555555555555558E-3", 
    "0", "NA", "0", "0.2857142857142857", "0", "0.32258064516129031", 
    "0", "0.16", "0,05mcg/kg/min", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0,1mcg/Kg/min", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "10ml/hr", "0", "0", "0", "30ml/h", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "10 ml/h", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), 
    cardiovas_score = c(NA, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 3, 0, 
    0, 4, 4, 4, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, NA, 
    0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), creatinine = c("0.62", "2.21", "NA", "1.25", 
    "1.84", "0.94", "0.77", "0.41", "1.58", "NA", "2.4500000000000002", 
    "0.21", "NA", "1.65", "2.77", "2.1800000000000002", "1.1299999999999999", 
    "0.49", "0.53", "1.34", "1.23", "0.8", "0.65", "2.9", "0.45", 
    "1.05", "0.72", "5.14", "0.65", "0.47", "1.46", "NA", "2.77", 
    "2.21", "0.97", "0.35", "NA", "1.83", "0.78", "0.45", "1.23", 
    "NA", "0.59", "1.21", "0.61", "0.75", "1.23", "0.74", "NA", 
    "0.88", "0.65", "3.48", "0.7", "0.88", "NA", "1.1499999999999999", 
    "0.59", "0.6", "0.41", "NA", "0.66", "0.72", "0.69", "NA", 
    "NA", "1.29", "0.8", "0.94", "0.48", "1.1399999999999999", 
    "0.85", "0.74", "0.86"), renal_score = c(0, 2, NA, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 2, 0, NA, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 
    0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, NA, 2, 2, 0, 0, NA, 1, 0, 0, 1, NA, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, NA, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 
    0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `SOFA SCORE` = c(0, 
    5, 3, 2, 7, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 0, 0, 9, 6, 6, 4, 3, 3, 7, 
    3, 1, 0, 2, 7, 2, 0, 8, 4, 0, 3, 1, 6, 4, 10, 2, 4, 5, 2, 
    0, 7, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 7, 2, 0, 1, 0, 5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 0, 0, 
    2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-73L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have tried

```
test <- glm(sofa_t0_deadoralive$outcome ~ resp_score + coag_score + liver_score + cardiovas_score + renal_score, family =  binomial)
```

Which outputs

```
Warning message:
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

And when I use

```
glm(formula = sofa_t0_deadoralive$outcome ~ resp_score + coag_score + 
    liver_score + cardiovas_score + renal_score, family = binomial)
```

I get

```
Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.9432  -0.5247   0.0000   0.5729   1.5111  

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)        2.543e+00  1.429e+00   1.779   0.0752 .
resp_score1       -5.534e-02  1.381e+00  -0.040   0.9680  
resp_score2       -8.189e-01  1.415e+00  -0.579   0.5627  
resp_score3       -1.803e+00  1.664e+00  -1.084   0.2784  
resp_score4       -1.639e+01  4.315e+03  -0.004   0.9970  
resp_scoreNA      -1.282e+00  1.460e+00  -0.878   0.3799  
coag_score1       -1.889e+00  1.538e+00  -1.228   0.2193  
coag_score2       -1.917e+01  4.706e+03  -0.004   0.9967  
coag_score3       -2.211e+01  1.075e+04  -0.002   0.9984  
coag_scoreNA      -1.777e+00  9.772e-01  -1.819   0.0690 .
liver_score1       3.463e+01  1.159e+04   0.003   0.9976  
liver_scoreNA     -1.833e+00  9.257e-01  -1.980   0.0478 *
cardiovas_score1          NA         NA      NA       NA  
cardiovas_score3  -2.795e-01  1.722e+00  -0.162   0.8710  
cardiovas_score4  -1.997e+01  2.782e+03  -0.007   0.9943  
cardiovas_scoreNA -1.747e+01  6.423e+03  -0.003   0.9978  
.
.
.
```

Why is R recognizing each score of resp_score, liver_score and cardiovas_score, in this example, as different categorical data instead of continuous? What can I do to fix it?

Any direction as to where to focus is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are only specifying the data frame for the outcome variable (`sofa_t0_deadoralive$outcome`), and you don't provide anything to the `data` argument for `glm()`. Are you sure it's relying on the variables of that same data frame? Or is it calling other vectors in your environment that happen to share the same name but are different (such as, maybe they're factor variables instead of numeric)?

Comment: Are those variables represented as factors? Have you tried coercing with as.numeric()?

Comment: Yes, they are represent as factors, and I have tried coercing with as.numeric without success.

Comment: @Phil I'm sorry, could you be a little more specific? I thought ```~ resp_score + coag_score + 
    liver_score + cardiovas_score + renal_score ``` would be the argument for ```glm()```, isn't it?

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate. Factors cannot be converted to 'numeric' with `as.numeric`. Need `as.numeric(as.character(.))`. Also DO NOT use `$` in formulae. and DO use data arguments for `glm`!!!

Comment: @dairelix it is, if you specify the data frame using the `data` argument. You did not do so in the code you provided. As for converting a vector of numbers from factor to numeric, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3418192/5221626

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a factor to integer\numeric without loss of information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information)

Comment: @IRTFM `as.numeric(levels(f))[f]` is more efficient than `as.numeric(as.character(f))`, as an FYI

Comment: I've been using `as.numeric(as.character(x))` for a long time... it seems to work OK.

Comment: @Phil question answered. It worked as per your suggestions.

Comment: @IRFTM I didn't say "much more effective" - they both do the job fine. I said "more efficient" in that it does the task quicker. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3418192/5221626

Answer (score 0):

I tried your dataset as follows:

```
myData <- structure(list(ID = c(13154920, 13201107, 13207948, 13234892, 
                  13082943, 13193903, 13283776, 13154288, 13269178, 13055690, 13207670, 
                  13220627, 13055009, 13044947, 13060589, 13201616, 13054278, 13160156, 
                  13160971, 13239318, 13321288, 13154966, 13165362, 12999835, 13223721, 
                  13064865, 13104602, 13036280, 13040507, 12964437, 13029805, 13029001, 
                  12993036, 13072516, 13060586, 13119819, 13040632, 13055908, 13059026, 
                  13207119, 13261022, 13259391, 13262499, 13207315, 13135316, 13233898, 
                  13181075, 13261607, 13186960, 13240091, 13260671, 13302375, 13021555, 
                  13062360, 13035346, 13077712, 13128769, 13267480, 13040172, 12977871, 
                  13090190, 13040530, 13100979, 13192142, 13289317, 13315577, 13044653, 
                  13079694, 13128639, 13207352, 13049409, 13210994, 13283675), 
           outcome = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                       0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                       1), 
           day = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                   0), 
           pa02 = c("121", "NA", "78.7", "69.099999999999994", "131", 
                    "26.3", "68.900000000000006", "74.099999999999994", "118", 
                    "404", "399", "NA", "NA", "73.7", "265", "75", "222", "112", 
                    "133", "77.900000000000006", "64.7", "84", "92.2", "107", 
                    "64.599999999999994", "56.6", "69.900000000000006", "130", 
                    "91.4", "NA", "111", "79.2", "86.9", "65.7", "94.5", "129", 
                    "NA", "157,0", "32,8", "160,0", "38,1", "61,7", "NA", "86,8", 
                    "86,5", "87,4", "143,0", "57,8", "NA", "88,6", "94,3", "NA", 
                    "70,0", "107,0", "57,2", "75,9", "148,0", "NA", "60,4", "NA", 
                    "NA", "148,0", "75,3", "75,4", "58", "46,4", "82,3", "189,0", 
                    "132,0", "96,5", "112,0", "67,0", "65"), 
           iot = c("0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", 
                   "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", 
                   "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
                   "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", 
                   "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", 
                   "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0"), 
           fio2 = c("0.23", "1", "0.6", "0.23", "1", "0.23", "0.23", "0.23", "0.4", "1", 
                    "0.23", "0.23", "0.23", "1", "0.23", "0.23", "0.23", "0.23", 
                    "0.5", "0.5", "0.23", "0.23", "0.23", "0.23", "0.75", "NA", 
                    "NA", "0.23", "0.1", "0.23", "NA", "0.23", "NA", "0.23", 
                    "1", "0.5", "0.4", "0.45", "0.23", "0.23", "0.7", "0.23", 
                    "0.23", "0.23", "0.23", "0.23", "1", "0.23", "0.23", "0.23", 
                    "0.23", "0.23", "0.23", "1", "0.23", "1", "0.23", "0.8", 
                    "0.23", "0.4", "0.23", "0.4", "0.23", "0.23", "0.23", "0.23", 
                    "0.3", "0.23", "0.8", "0.23", "0.3", "0.23", "0.23"), 
           resp_syst = c("526.08695652173913", "NA", "131.16666666666669", "300.43478260869563", "131", 
                         "114.34782608695652", "299.56521739130437", "322.17391304347819", 
                         "295", "404", "1734.782608695652", "NA", "NA", "73.7", "1152.1739130434783", 
                         "326.08695652173913", "965.21739130434776", "486.95652173913044", 
                         "266", "155.80000000000001", "281.30434782608694", "365.21739130434781", 
                         "400.86956521739131", "465.21739130434781", "86.133333333333326", 
                         "NA", "NA", "565.21739130434776", "914", "NA", "NA", "344.3478260869565", 
                         "NA", "285.6521739130435", "94.5", "258", "NA", "348.88888888888886", 
                         "142.60869565217391", "695.6521739130435", "54.428571428571431", 
                         "268.26086956521738", "NA", "377.39130434782606", "376.08695652173913", 
                         "380", "143", "251.30434782608694", "NA", "385.21739130434776", 
                         "409.99999999999994", "NA", "304.3478260869565", "107", "248.69565217391303", 
                         "75.900000000000006", "643.47826086956513", "NA", "262.60869565217388", 
                         "NA", "NA", "370", "327.39130434782606", "327.82608695652175", 
                         "252.17391304347825", "201.7391304347826", "274.33333333333331", 
                         "821.73913043478262", "165", "419.56521739130432", "373.33333333333337", 
                         "291.30434782608694", "282.60869565217388"), 
           resp_score = c(0, NA, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, NA, NA, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 
                          3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 4, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 1, NA, 2, 4, 2, NA, 
                          1, 2, 0, 4, 2, NA, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, NA, 1, 0, NA, 1, 3, 2, 
                          4, 0, NA, 2, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2), 
           platelets = c("NA", "363000", "NA", "NA", "620000", "NA", 
                         "419000", "277000", "NA", "NA", "277000", "255000", "NA", 
                         "185000", "318000", "296000", "182000", "48000", "129000", 
                         "260000", "254000", "213000", "132000", "293000", "NA", "99000", 
                         "297000", "227000", "174000", "172000", "76000", "NA", "242000", 
                         "181000", "90000", "NA", "NA", "264000", "331000", "237000", 
                         "279000", "NA", "214000", "NA", "NA", "283000", "416000", 
                         "349000", "NA", "243000", "635000", "100000", "165000", "343000", 
                         "NA", "423000", "206000", "NA", "439000", "NA", "358000", 
                         "253000", "130000", "NA", "498000", "415000", "236000", "440000", 
                         "218000", "300000", "190000", "244000", "275000"), 
           coag_score = c(NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3,
                          1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, NA, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, NA, 0, 0, 2, NA, 
                          NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 
                          NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 1, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
           bilirrubin = c("NA", "0.4", "NA", "0.5", "0.3", "NA", 
                          "0.9", "NA", "0.4", "NA", "0.5", "NA", "NA", "1.1000000000000001", 
                          "NA", "0.3", "NA", "0.5", "NA", "0.3", "0.3", "NA", "NA", 
                          "0.4", "NA", "0.5", "0.4", "0.4", "1", "0.5", "NA", "NA", 
                          "NA", "NA", "NA", "0.3", "0.3", "1", "0.7", "0.3", "1.4", 
                          "NA", "NA", "0.3", "0.3", "0.3", "0.7", "0.4", "NA", "NA", 
                          "NA", "0.7", "0.6", "0.5", "NA", "NA", "0.3", "0.3", "NA", 
                          "NA", "NA", "0.4", "0.3", "NA", "NA", "0.4", "1.1000000000000001", 
                          "NA", "0.5", "1.4", "0.4", "0.6", "0.7"), 
           liver_score = c(NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, 
                           NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 
                           0, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 
                           0, 0, 0), 
           pam = c("NA", "80.666666666666671", "73.333333333333329", "83.333333333333329", 
                   "84.666666666666671", "100.6666666666667", 
                   "101", "100", "95", "69.333333333333329", "93.666666666666671", 
                   "70", "91.666666666666671", "70.666666666666671", "81.666666666666671", 
                   "71.333333333333329", "95.333333333333329", "92", "77.666666666666671", 
                   "84.333333333333329", "90", "80", "96.333333333333329", "93.333333333333329", 
                   "69.333333333333329", "57.333333333333343", "80", "63", "81.666666666666671", 
                   "80", "76.666666666666671", "90", "62.666666666666657", "89.333333333333329", 
                   "87.333333333333329", "72.333333333333329", "93.333333333333329", 
                   "87.666666666666671", "105.3333333333333", "107.6666666666667", 
                   "69.333333333333329", "111.3333333333333", "75.666666666666671", 
                   "103", "85.333333333333329", "86.666666666666671", "64.333333333333329", 
                   "93.333333333333329", "87.333333333333329", "100", "106.6666666666667", 
                   "96.666666666666671", "102", "98.666666666666671", "83.333333333333329", 
                   "73.666666666666671", "95.333333333333329", "81", "93.333333333333329", 
                   "62.666666666666657", "83.333333333333329", "93", "92.333333333333329", 
                   "73.333333333333329", "87.333333333333329", "74.333333333333329", 
                   "95.333333333333329", "80.333333333333329", "83.333333333333329", 
                   "96.333333333333329", "97.666666666666671", "91.666666666666671", 
                   "85.333333333333329"), 
           catecolamine = c("10 ml/h", "0,1 mcg/kg/min", "0", "0", 
                            "0,1mcg/kg/min", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0,8 mcg/kg/min", 
                            "0,1 mcg/kg/min", "0", "0", "0,3mcg/kg/min", "0,15 mcg/kg/min", 
                            "0,13mcg/kg/min", "6ml/h", "0", "0", "0,03mcg/kg/min", "0", 
                            "0", "0", "0", "9mL/h", "0", "0", "0.45", "5.5555555555555558E-3", 
                            "0", "NA", "0", "0.2857142857142857", "0", "0.32258064516129031", 
                            "0", "0.16", "0,05mcg/kg/min", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                            "0", "0", "0,1mcg/Kg/min", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                            "0", "0", "10ml/hr", "0", "0", "0", "30ml/h", "0", "0", "0", 
                            "0", "0", "0", "0", "10 ml/h", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), 
           cardiovas_score = c(NA, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 3, 0, 
                               0, 4, 4, 4, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, NA, 
                               0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 4, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 
                               0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
           creatinine = c("0.62", "2.21", "NA", "1.25", "1.84", "0.94", 
                          "0.77", "0.41", "1.58", "NA", "2.4500000000000002", 
                          "0.21", "NA", "1.65", "2.77", "2.1800000000000002", 
                          "1.1299999999999999", "0.49", "0.53", "1.34", 
                          "1.23", "0.8", "0.65", "2.9", "0.45", "1.05", "0.72", 
                          "5.14", "0.65", "0.47", "1.46", "NA", "2.77", "2.21", 
                          "0.97", "0.35", "NA", "1.83", "0.78", "0.45", "1.23", 
                          "NA", "0.59", "1.21", "0.61", "0.75", "1.23", "0.74", 
                          "NA", "0.88", "0.65", "3.48", "0.7", "0.88", "NA", 
                          "1.1499999999999999", "0.59", "0.6", "0.41", "NA", 
                          "0.66", "0.72", "0.69", "NA", "NA", "1.29", "0.8", 
                          "0.94", "0.48", "1.1399999999999999", "0.85", "0.74", 
                          "0.86"), 
           renal_score = c(0, 2, NA, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 2, 0, NA, 1, 2, 2, 
                           1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, NA, 2, 
                           2, 0, 0, NA, 1, 0, 0, 1, NA, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, NA, 
                           0, 0, 3, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 
                           1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
           `SOFA SCORE` = c(0, 5, 3, 2, 7, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 0, 0, 9, 6, 6, 4, 
                            3, 3, 7, 3, 1, 0, 2, 7, 2, 0, 8, 4, 0, 3, 1, 6, 4, 
                            10, 2, 4, 5, 2, 0, 7, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 7, 2, 0, 1, 0, 
                            5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 
                            2, 0, 1, 2, 2)
           ), 
      row.names = c(NA, -73L), 
      class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
      )

test <- glm(outcome ~ resp_score + coag_score + liver_score + 
              cardiovas_score + renal_score, data = myData)
summary(test)
```

The only thing that I removed from your command is `Family = binomial` and got the following results:

```
    Call:
glm(formula = outcome ~ resp_score + coag_score + liver_score + 
    cardiovas_score + renal_score, data = myData)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-0.88541  -0.16677   0.09191   0.11459   0.68038  

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      0.93077    0.13547   6.871 4.17e-07 ***
resp_score      -0.02268    0.06703  -0.338   0.7381    
coag_score      -0.27004    0.12882  -2.096   0.0468 *  
liver_score      0.47799    0.42628   1.121   0.2733    
cardiovas_score -0.11254    0.05819  -1.934   0.0650 .  
renal_score     -0.20551    0.10250  -2.005   0.0564 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.1415673)

    Null deviance: 6.9667  on 29  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 3.3976  on 24  degrees of freedom
  (43 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 33.793

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

So I didn't get any factors in variables. I think somehow your dataset storing variables as factors. I don't know if it's going to solve your problem but just wanted to share my experience with this very dataset. You can try it my way if you like.